# str.replace unbalanced parenthesis error in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

I have 2 dataframes. Below is how data looks like

**Find**
[image]

**Replace**
[image]

I am searching for each `keyword` in `current_title` and if found i am replacing it against the corresponding `keywordLength` in the `Find` dataframe. Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
df_find = pd.read_csv(input_path_find)
df_replace = pd.read_csv(input_path_replace)

#replace
for i in range(df_replace.shape[0]):
    df_find.current_title=df_find.current_title.str.replace(df_replace.keyword.loc[i],df_replace.keywordLength.loc[i],case=False)
```

However, when i execute the code, i am getting below error

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-134bbf2a1cb4> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(df_replace.shape[0]):
----> 2     df_find.current_title=df_find.current_title.str.replace(df_replace.keyword.loc[i],df_replace.keywordLength.loc[i],case=False)

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.pyc in replace(self, pat, repl, n, case, flags)
   1504     def replace(self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=True, flags=0):
   1505         result = str_replace(self._data, pat, repl, n=n, case=case,
-> 1506                              flags=flags)
   1507         return self._wrap_result(result)
   1508 

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.pyc in str_replace(arr, pat, repl, n, case, flags)
    326         if not case:
    327             flags |= re.IGNORECASE
--> 328         regex = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)
    329         n = n if n >= 0 else 0
    330 

c:\python27\lib\re.pyc in compile(pattern, flags)
    192 def compile(pattern, flags=0):
    193     "Compile a regular expression pattern, returning a pattern object."
--> 194     return _compile(pattern, flags)
    195 
    196 def purge():

c:\python27\lib\re.pyc in _compile(*key)
    249         p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    250     except error, v:
--> 251         raise error, v # invalid expression
    252     if not bypass_cache:
    253         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Any help?

**Edit:** error appears when `str(df_replace.keywordLength.loc[i])` has values containing any of the `(*)+[\` special characters

Comment: What is in `df_replace.keywordLength.loc[i]`?

Comment: Its in the Replace table. second column. It has length of the text corpus from the previous column. Numbers to be precise

Comment: So I haven't been able to duplicate the error without source data, but, given that it's `.str.replace` and they're numbers, have you tried `str(df_replace.keywordLength.loc[i])` for your replacement value? Or `.replace`, with no `.str`?

Comment: ok, exactly where error appears when str(df_replace.keywordLength.loc[i]) has values containing any of the ``(*)+[\`` special characters

Answer (score 0):

[str.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) is expecting a regular expression as the first argument. You need to [scape](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) the pattern string before passing it to `str.replace`:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df_find = pd.read_csv(input_path_find)
df_replace = pd.read_csv(input_path_replace)

#replace
for i in range(df_replace.shape[0]):
        df_find.current_title = df_find.current_title.str.replace(
            re.scape(df_replace.keyword.loc[i]),
            df_replace.keywordLength.loc[i],
            case=False
        )
```